# Child elements in div won't fadeTo() in IE

Tags: jquery, fadeto

This is strange to me. This code:

```
$(".layover").fadeTo("fast", 0.0);
$(".layover").hover(function() {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.9);
},
function() {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.0);
});
```

..works just fine on all browsers except IE7 and IE8. It even works (slowly) in IE6 (screams!) In IE7 and IE8 this code will NOT fade out child elements namely `img` tags. The `img` just sit there unaffected. However, if I enable "compatibility mode" in IE8, it works as expected. See [this example page](http://xnation.gotmarci.com/).

Is there a bit I'm missing in my JavaScript to help IE play nice? Can I force compatibility mode in IE?

And I know someone is going to comment on the FOUC. I'm working on that too.

UPDATE: Here's the CSS portion

```
div.layover {
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#fff;
height:106px;
width:312px;
}
```

Comment: What does your css look like for .layover and its children? I am getting some mixed results based on positioning.

Comment: patrick, sorry for not including that portion. It's in my original post now. Thanks.

Comment: aside: I don't think you need "display:inline-block", I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your main question, but I believe changing your first line to this would help fix your FOUC:

```
$(".layover").hide();
```

Comment: $(".layover:).fadeOut("fast") would be more appropriate.

Comment: My understanding is that upon page load, he wants the .layovers to be immediately invisible. Only fade in on mousein, fade out on mouse out. In which case, no, .hide(); would be more appropriate.

Comment: If they're completely hidden, which `.hide()` does, making them take up 0 room on the page, how would they ever have a `mouseenter` event?  He's giving them no visibility, not removing their space from the document, this is very different.